# Mobiles Charge Density of NMOS

Tags: charge, semiconductor-physics

I'm trying to get a better understand of the derivation of current for the NMOS.

What I don't understand is the formula for the mobile charge density: $$ Q = (W)(Cox)(VGS-VTH) $$

Where $Cox$ is the capacitance of the silicon oxide insulator, $VGS$ is the voltage difference between the gate and source, $VTH$ is the threshold voltage and $W$ is the width of the NMOS.

I don't get why the difference between $VGS$ and the $VTH$ is needed? Could someone elaborate a bit on this equation? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because only if VGS > VTH does the conduction band overlap with the Fermi level.
Below the threshold voltage their are very few electrons in the conduction band of the channel semiconductor. The density of conduction band electrons is largely determined by thermal effects.

As the threshold voltage is reached the conduction band starts to get low enough in energy to become populated. Increasing the voltage further (beyond VTH) brings down the conduction band further and the added electrons in the conduction band leads to a linear effect in VGS - VTH.

Comment: This is not completely correct. In particular, there is no need for a conduction band overlap with the Fermi level.

Answer (score 0):

The correct explanation is the following. At the threshold voltage the Fermi level is usually below the conduction band edge but the density of inversion electrons becomes comparable to the majority carriers (holes) of the substrate. Above the threshold voltage, because the Fermi level get close to the conduction band edge,  the density of electrons becomes so high and reactive to changes in gate voltage that any further shifts in Fermi level with respect to the conduction band edge become negligible and you eventually get a linear dependence of electron channel density on the difference of gate and threshold voltage just like in a plate capacitor. The threshold voltage is actually defined as a voltage obtained by the intercept of the extrapolation of this linear dependence with the voltage axis and approximated by convenient formulas.